# Invalid Argument error for a function

Tags: c#

Function 
MouldingDetail_UpdateDetails(string mouldItem, string mouldQty, int core, int freerider, decimal plate, string plant, string systemMode)

after passing
 MouldingDetail_UpdateDetails( "AX5M211531", '1', 1, 1, '0.5', "CMLD1", string.Empty) when I pass the following as values it shows "invalid arguments"

Comment: You are passing in the decimal how? '0.5' obviously is not the way you would pass a decimal. 0.5m should help.

Comment: Yes, as the answer suggests, that '1' is a char, not a string.

Comment: @OguzOzgul - 0.5d is a double, not a decimal. 0.5m would be decimal.

Comment: it should be m, correct, and thanks

Comment: You are using different quotations to pass your first argument (`"AX5M211531"`) and your second argument (`'1'`). Single quotes are for `char` types and double quotes are for `string` types. Your method defines `string mouldQty`, not `char mouldQty`. Additionally, `'0.5'` is completely invalid. You're supposed to be passing a decimal, which you've for some reason encased in single quotes as if it were a `char`.

Comment: Thanks , the fault was in Passing the second argument as char and decimal as 0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the method's signature:

```
MouldingDetail_UpdateDetails(
     string,
     string,
     int,
     int,
     decimal,
     string,
     string
)
```

Yet, you're passing:

```
MouldingDetail_UpdateDetails(
     "AX5M211531" (string), // Good
     '1' (char),            // Wrong! This is supposed to be a string! use "1" instead
      1 (int),              // Good
      1 (int),              // Good
      '0.5' (invalid char), // Wrong! This shouldn't even compile. Use 0.5M without the single quotes
      "CMLD1" (string),     // Good
      string.Empty (string) // Good
);
```

Comment: @Sharon No problem at all. I hope you understood your errors! :) If this answer helped you solve your problem, please accept it. You'll get a little reputation from it!

Answer (score 2):

'1' isn't a valid string, it's a char instead.

For a proper understanding please read - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs7y5x0x(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Ans we have decimal '0.5'

Comment: I have seen that, just wanted OP to understand about basic C# data types.